# Unable to retrieve an Array of objects posted to Django from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

My Javascript:

```
var postData = {
    customer: 'test', 
    order: 1, 
    boxes: [
        {
            "size":"2",
            "color":"1",
            "colorNumber":"1",
            "barCode":"1234567890",
            "barCodePic":"",
        },
        {
            "size":"3",
            "color":"1",
            "colorNumber":"2",
            "barCode":"0987654321",
            "barCodePic":"",
        }
    ]
}

jQuery.post("http://10.0.1.7:8001/bapi/order/", postData );
```

My Python:

```
print 'Customer:', request.POST.get('customer', None)                   
print 'Order:', request.POST.get('order', None)                         
print 'get - boxes:', request.POST.get('boxes', None)                    
print 'get - boxes[]:', request.POST.get('boxes[]', None)               
print 'getlist - boxes[]:', request.POST.getlist('boxes[]')             
print 'getlist - boxes:', request.POST.getlist('boxes')                                                                      
print request.POST
```

The output:

```
Customer: test
Order: 1
get - boxes: None
get - boxes[]: None
getlist - boxes[]: []
getlist - boxes: []
<QueryDict: {u'customer': [u'test'], u'boxes[1][barCode]': [u'0987654321'], u'boxes[0][size]': [u'2'], u'boxes[1][colorNumber]': [u'2'], u'boxes[1][size]': [u'3'], u'boxes[0][colorNumber]': [u'1'], u'boxes[1][color]': [u'1'], u'boxes[0][barCode]': [u'1234567890'], u'boxes[1][barCodePic]': [u''], u'boxes[0][barCodePic]': [u''], u'boxes[0][color]': [u'1'], u'order': [u'1']}>
```

Nothing I do gets me the list as I would expect. I'm hoping to get a python list containing dictionaries for each 'box' object.

I've been advised to use 'boxes[]' as the parameter name in javascript, so my post data would be:

```
var postData = {
    customer: 'test', 
    order: 1, 
    'boxes[]': [
        {
            "size":"2",
            "color":"1",
            "colorNumber":"1",
            "barCode":"1234567890",
            "barCodePic":"",
        },
        {
            "size":"3",
            "color":"1",
            "colorNumber":"2",
            "barCode":"0987654321",
            "barCodePic":"",
        }
    ]
}
```

When trying that, the output is:

```
Customer: test
Order: 1
get - boxes: None
get - boxes[]: [object Object]
getlist - boxes[]: [u'[object Object]', u'[object Object]']
getlist - boxes: []
POST BELOW
<QueryDict: {u'customer': [u'test'], u'boxes[]': [u'[object Object]', u'[object Object]'], u'order': [u'1']}>
```

You can see right in the QueryDict that's just a list of unicode strings containing '[object Object']. No object data is actually there.

Comment: This was previously marked as a duplicate in which the issue was solved by adding [] to the javascript parameter name, but as you can see in this revised post - that hasn't resolved the issue. This issue differs in that it is a list of objects. Not just a simple list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to encode the JavaScript objects first. Those cannot be passed directly via GET or POST parameters.

Try calling JSON.stringify() on the JavaScript objects before you `POST` it with jQuery (that is, the arbitrary data enclosed with `{ "size":"3",  "color":"1" ... }`). For example:

```
[

    JSON.stringify({
        "size":"2",
        "color":"1",
        "colorNumber":"1",
        "barCode":"1234567890",
        "barCodePic":"",
    }),
    JSON.stringify({
        "size":"3",
        "color":"1",
        "colorNumber":"2",
        "barCode":"0987654321",
        "barCodePic":"",
    })

]
```

Then within Python, use something like to decode it:

```
import json
box_0_string = request.POST.get('boxes[]')[0]
box_0_dict = json.loads(box_0_string)
```

To get the individual JSON objects.

Comment: Thank you! I thought I could post native objects around in a POST, but yea they do indeed need to be serialized.  Thanks for the help!!